# How to search from varchar column with - on it

Tags: sql-server, excel, where-clause, varchar

I am trying to search from SQL table where my column where to search is varchar type and my keyword for the search should be imported from Excel, like this:

SELECT table.column FROM table WHERE column="for example"42-3

So, the column consists varchar type variables formed with few numbers then "-" and then one number. To Excel I write for example 42-3 and macro should find every row with 42-3 from that table.

I think somehow I should convert it or take it apart when I could only search by numbers but I don't know how to do that when there is - in the variable.

EDIT:

so, in my SQL table I have a first column where are varchar variables 42-1,42-1,42-2,45-1,46-1... second column I have numbers 1,5,11,3,1,6,2... third column I have amounts 300,52 , 200,10 , 712,31 , 0,44... I should make a search with WHERE command for for example WHERE column1=42-1

I can write this "42-1" straight from excel as string format so that is not a problem, only that the character type is in varchar format and consists - so I can not convert it to integer.

Comment: Can you give sample data and desired results?   I don't know Excel macros, so I have no idea what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Try using '%' operator

```
Select * from tableName where column1 like value1+'%'
```